# Import Excel sheets to one excel file using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I've tried many ways of putting loop of data to one excel sheet with xlsxwriter, pandas etc but nothing works how I want it. So Im obtaining alot of data. Right now Im making a new excel sheet for every new 'sampleid'. I want then to take every row with just the data (not the headers bq/kg etc) and put into a master excelfile with one sheet for all 'sampleid'. Is there maybe a way to rewrite this code to loop it so it puts the new 'sampleid' to the same worksheet but just a row lower?
Edit: I uploaded picture of how the sheets looks like[This is how all the sheets looks like and i only want the values from row 3 and down.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSAKp.png)

```
        if sampleid!="000":
            print(sampleid)
            print ("Isotope \t", "A (Bq/kg) +/- 1 sd \t MDA (Bq/kg)")
            #sampleid = workbook.add_worksheet()
            
                    
                
            if create_an_excel_file_with_one_table:
                worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(sampleid)
                worksheet.set_column('A:AA', 25)



        
       

            for i in range(len(activity)):
                if isotopes[i]=="Pb-210" :
                        worksheet.write(row+2, 0, isotopes[i])
                        worksheet.write(row+2, 1,str(np.round(activity_pbc[i]/mass,8)))
                        worksheet.write(row+2, 2, '+/-')
                        worksheet.write(row+2, 3,str(np.round(sigma_activity_pbc[i]/mass,8)))
                        worksheet.write(row+2, 4,str(MDA[i]/mass))     
      
 
                worksheet.write("B1", sampleid, bold)
                worksheet.write("A1", "Sampleid:", bold)
                worksheet.write("A2", "Isotope", bold)
                worksheet.write("B2","Activity (Bq/kg)", bold)
                worksheet.write("C2",'+/-', bold)
                worksheet.write("D2",'1 sd', bold)
                worksheet.write("E2","MDA (Bq/kg)", bold)
                worksheet.write(row,3,'Detector:', bold)
                worksheet.write(row,4,detector)
                worksheet.set_default_row(hide_unused_rows=True)
                                
                #worksheet.write(i,0, "SampleID")
    #worksheet.write(i,20, sampleid)         #worksheet.write(i,1, sampleid)
    workbook.close()
```

Comment: not going into your specific code you could use pandas .read_excel to read your many sheet output into a dict of dataframes and then concat the data frames and write it to an excel, somthing like: pd.concat(pd.read_excel(<fmany_sheet_file>).values()).to_excel(<single_sheet_file>)

Comment: Thanks but what do I put in values()?

Comment: nothing, .values() should give the values of the dict

Comment: okay, I tried but I get following error: 'TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable'

Comment: so I'm probably wrong, let me check

Comment: forgot to specify sheet_name=None, probably best toadd header=None as well so here goes:
pd.concat(pd.read_excel(<many_sheet_file>, sheet_name=None, header=None).values()).to_excel(<single_sheet_file>)

Comment: Thanks it works fine but it takes also the second row which is a part of the header, do you know how to do it so it wont take the second row aswell?

Comment: hard to say without seeing what the sheets look like, try  removing the 'header=None' part

Comment: I updated the post with picture fo the excel sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in my comments, without going into specific code, you could use pandas to read all sheets, manipulate them however you like - in this case take the 3rd row and on, and concat to write back to a single sheet file:

```
df_list = pd.read_excel(<many_sheet_file>, sheet_name=None, header=None).values())
df_new_list = []
for df in df_list:
    df_new_list.append(df.iloc[2:])
df_all = pd.concat(df_new_list)
all_df.to_excel(<single_sheet_file>)
```